# Show paragraph with ellipsis in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I know how to use ellipsis with the Text widget. `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis` does the job very well. But my problem is it actually displays only one line. I am trying to make a layout something similar to the below image:

[image: Expected design]

How to do this in Flutter?

It is a common layout and it is sad that it isn't documented anywhere :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `overflow` in addition to `maxlines`.  if you need to adhere to a really tight fixed height then you can easily calculate what maxlines should be based upon your font size.

```
Text(
  'my super long string',
  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  maxLines: 3,
),
```

Comment: Thanks. But little bit confused, can you edit the answer and post a small snippet showing Text widget displaying two lines?

Comment: Thanks, blaneyneil, much appreciated :)

Comment: Wrap the Text widget with Expanded if it doesn't work.